# I keep getting the message of "operand type doesn't match operator"

Tags: pascal, turbo-pascal

Here are the rules of a simple game:

> 2 players a and b hide their right hands behind their backs. Each chooses to hold a certain number of fingers from 0 to 5 always behind their backs. Both players show their hands at the same time. If the sum of the numbers of fingers shown is a pair, player a wins, otherwise player b wins. The problem is determining the winner by the computer

I've tried this programming in Turbo Pascal but they keep showing the  ":" expected but ";" found or the  "operand type doesn't match operator"

```
Program parity;

    var nbr1;nbr2,remainder:integer;
    begin
    read(nbr1,nbr2);
    tot:=nbr1+nbr2;
    remainder:=tot mod 2;   
    if remainder=0 then begin write('winner is A')
    end
    else write('winner is B');
end.
```

Comment: You need to look really carefully for the wrong character in the code. But don't blindly trust the error message.

Comment: Isn't it this `var nbr1;nbr2,remainder:integer;1 should be `var nbr1, nbr2, remainder:integer;`.  Improving your code formatting would help spot issues..

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clean up your code formatting.

```
program parity;
var 
  nbr1; nbr2, remainder : integer;

begin
  read(nbr1, nbr2);
  tot := nbr1 + nbr2;
  remainder := tot mod 2;
   
  if remainder = 0 then 
  begin 
    write('winner is A')
  end
  else 
    write('winner is B');

end.
```

Your line `nbr1; nbr2, remainder : integer;` has an extra terminator so your compiler sees it as thought you'd written:

```
nbr1;
nbr2, remainder : integer;
```

It thinks you're missing a type on the declaration of `nbr1`, but I strongly suggest you just typoed when writing: `nbr1, nbr2, remainder : integer;`